# Resize UIImage for Portrait and landscape modes

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have some images designed for portrait mode of iPad . they are designed to cover full screen, now when i rotate the ipad to landscape I adjust the imageview's frae to cover ipad screeen in landscape mode, but that abruptly disturbs the aspect ratio and scale of image , How can i resize the image preserving the aspect ratio
Secondly I have a tableview with thumbnail image , those thumbnail images are saved by user  ( using NSUserDefaults) , but this is causing my tableview to scroll slowly.. i know we can use lazy loading if i m getting images from web...but what in this situation..

Please help.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question: you need to set the [contentMode property of the UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode), which is inherited from UIView. The default is UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, but I suspect you want UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

For the second: it's lazy loading again, I'm afraid. Table views are entirely oriented around cells being allocated only when needed, and you probably don't want to load images synchronously when creating cells since that'll lead to annoying user interface stalls. Particularly on the older devices and on the iPods, the disk speed just isn't very good and by storing in the NSUserDefaults you're requiring a costly conversion. It might be faster to put them in your documents or cache folder and keep filenames in the user defaults.

Answer (score 0):

AspectFill will maintain the aspect ratio and fill the full container
AspectFit will maintain the aspect ratio and fill the container until one dimension hits the boundary - so there will be some border around the image.

How are you loading the thumbnails?  If they are small you can either store the image it/themselves in an NSDictionary (be careful about modifying it while editing it though!) or if there are lots you could store the file references in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using different images for portrait and landscape versions... and for tableview i ended up using lazyloading